# Limit post edits?

Tags: wordpress

Is there a way to limit the number of times a post can be edited in WordPress?  I'm not looking to limit revisions stored in the db.  I would like the user to only be able to edit there post 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a counter on save post and check before update post. If counter crose limit you can return without saving post..

Here is the example....

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'check_for_counter' );
function check_for_count( $ppost_id ){

   if(wp_is_post_autosave($post_id) || wp_is_post_revision($post_id)) {
        return $post_id;
   }

   if(!current_user_can("edit_post", $post_id))
        return $post_id;

   $count = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'revision_counter', true );

   if( empty($count) ){
      update_post_meta( $post_id, 'revision_counter', 1 );
   }else{
     $count += 1;
     update_post_meta( $post_id, 'revision_counter', $count );
   }

   if( $count == 3 ){
     return $post_id;
   }
}
```

Please Note that I have never tested it but may resolve your problem.